# Is there anyway of making json data readable by a Google spider?

Tags: json, seo, web-crawler

Is it possible to make JSON data readable by a Google spider?

Say for instance that I have a JSON feed that contains the data for an e-commerce site.  This JSON data is used to populate a human-readable page in the users browser.  (I.E. The translation from JSON data to human displayed page is done inside the users browser; not my choice, just what I've been given to work with, its an old legacy CGI application and not an actual server-side scripting language.)

My concern here is that, the google spiders will not be able to pickup/directly link to the item in question when a user clicks on it in google, being presented with an index page full of all the items, rather than being linked directly to the item they clicked on.

Is there anyway of "informing" the google spider in the JSON that what they should feed the user a different link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a wrapper page in server-side code around the JSON data, and respond to requests with either the wrapper or the regular version depending on the User-Agent.

Comment: Isn't it frowned upon by google to show their spider something that is different from what a regular visitor sees?

Comment: I believe that it would be OK in this case.

Answer (score 5):

While Google does crawl and index JavaScript in some circumstances, it's still best to serve "normal" (X)HTML content if at all possible. In this case, it would help to know the rest of the site's setup, in particular: is the JSON content just used to create a feed of links to the product pages (with static content) or are all product pages also generated by JSON feeds? If the feed is only used to point to the actual product pages (which are static) then one way to make the product pages discoverable could be to create a HTML sitemap page or some other alternate form of navigation. A XML Sitemap file can also help, but I would recommend not using it as the sole way of making the product pages discoverable.

If all of the content is only accessible through JSON feeds, then I think you will have to make some bigger changes if you want that content to be accessible through search results.

One way to handle it could also be to use the new JavaScript crawling/indexing proposal, which basically would result in a headless browser being set up between your site and Google: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ (whether setting this up or revamping the rest of the site is easier is hard to say :-))