# How to add html content generated by json call to page generated html code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jquery

I have a page. Which contain json method to load data. I call this method on page load. It works properly. The problem is when I view source of that page I don't see the generated code.

My concern is the search engine will never see the content even if end user see it.

Is there anyway to add it? If so how it can be done?

Here is the example of code I use

```
    $(function(){

    //Call to the server to get data.

    var content = "Some data"; //from the json call

    $("#content").html(content);

    });




});
```

Comment: If possible, make the same pages being able to be loaded as actual page as well by its own url. It's that simple ;) Github works nicely that way :-)

Comment: check this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084003/will-content-loaded-by-ajax-affect-seo-search-engines][1]

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all search engines will not recognize content inserted into a page from Ajax/Javascript, this is why you need to load this content with in the page if you want the search engine to recognize it.

Comment: If you noticed I asked if there a way. If you cannot provide a solution you don't answer you comment the question.

Comment: Sorry it's not what you wanted to see, but it is a valid answer.  Good luck.

Comment: Actually, have a look at this: http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/06/making-seo-friendly-ajax-easy/

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to me a copy of [what's asked over here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25361/making-json-page-which-renders-on-document-ready-indexable) and in [Is there anyway of making json data readable by a Google spider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595182/is-there-anyway-of-making-json-data-readable-by-a-google-spider)

So, Progressive enhancement and Unobtrusive JavaScript are the way out..

In addition to these, optionally, but importantly, test the crawlability of your app: see what the crawler sees with "[Fetch as Googlebot](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587)".